# Meaning of "View v" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-view

I am trying to implement button click handling in my Android app.

In the XML layout file that includes my button, I added the following line to my `Button` XML element:

```xml
android:onClick="handleClick"
```

I also defined a method with the following signature in the `Activity` that uses this layout:

```java
public void handleClick() { /* ... */ }
```

However, when I ran my app with this code, it crashed. I was able to fix this crash by updating my method signature to:

```java
public void handleClick(View v) { /* ... */ }
```

but I don't understand why I am required to include this `View` parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you might want to use your `handleClick` method for 2 or more Buttons in your XML.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="handleClick"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="handleClick"/>
```

In that case it could be unclear which button triggers the callback. The `View v` helps you identify that e.g.

```
public void handleClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {

    } else if(v.getId() == R.id.button2) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `View` argument supplied represents the `View` that received the click event. This may be useful if you reuse the `handleClick` method for multiple `View`s (in which case, you could inspect the `id` of the `View` passed to the method to determine which `View` was clicked, as illustrated by [Enzokie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45271025/2911458)).

**You must include this `View` parameter when defining your method even if you do not use it in your click logic**. This is because [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) is used to locate the method corresponding to the name you supplied in XML, and the method name, parameter count, and parameter types are all required to [uniquely define a method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature#Java_2) in Java. Check out [this section of the `View` source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L4730-L4761) to see exactly how this reflective lookup works!

Comment: Thanks! Awesome answer.

Comment: Holy cow, this is the source code behind "View"? Its huge.

Comment: Haha, yes, the `View` class is a behemoth!

Answer (score 1):

The **View v** is the object of your xml file which is referred in your **onCreate** method. 
To refer any component from xml you have to use **v** to gets its id of the component.

**Condition**

> You have give id to the component in xml if you want to use **onClick** in your class file.

Comment: Thank you! I understand.